# Android popup like in default keyboard

Tags: android

I need to draw popup like in default keyboard.
[Screenshot.](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/36763140/how.png)
How can i do this ?

P.S. Soryy, but my reputation is not enough to post images.

Comment: Do you mean to place a View over another view when the second has a long press?

Comment: I want to draw zoomed area of view under finger and move it on finger move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the `popupKey` method in the [Android SDK](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#uX1GffpyOZk/core/java/android/inputmethodservice/KeyboardView.java&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/inputmethodservice/%20popUpKey&ct=rc&cd=1&l=1000). When you long press you will have to use a `miniKeyboardContainer` to draw the popup which will display the characters specific to that key's id. Have a look [here](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#search/&q=package%3aandroid.git.kernel.org%20file%3aandroid/inputmethodservice/%20popUpKey&type=cs) to see how the Android keyboard deals with the `popupKey` behaviour.

Comment: Greath thanks! I've forgot to search "popup" on delevepoer.android.com. Your answer helped me to find PopupWindow class!